# Split Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a db with 2 columns, key and value. record:

> ```
> ------------------------------------
> | key |          value             |
> ------------------------------------
> |  A  | 1,desc 1;2,desc 2;3,desc 3 |
> ------------------------------------
> ```

I want to split value column become json format:

```
[{"key":"1","value":"desc 1"},{"key":"2","value":"desc 2"},{"key":"3", "value":"desc 3"}]
```

Where I am put split function? in service? because too dificult for 2 split. How to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Bobby

Comment: how are you getting this data? What you have copied there looks like the command line interface for mysql. Are you trying to parse that string exactly as it's written above? Because if you are pulling this data from the db with java, you can get the string directly without  all the - and | chars. If you do need to use this string exactly as written, start by removing - and | and only grab the 4th line

Answer (score 3):

That depends on how your application is usually working with this value. If the usual case is using some specific data from this column, I would parse this at repository level already:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // You actually get this from DB
    String value = "1,desc 1;2,desc 2;3,desc 3";

    JSONArray j = new JSONArray();
    Stream.of(value.split(";")).forEach((pair -> {
        String[] keyValue = pair.split(",");

        JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
        o.put("key", keyValue[0]);
        o.put("value", keyValue[1]);
        j.put(o);

    }));


    System.out.println(j);

}
```